# Unable to install bazel 0.4.5 in MacOS 10.13

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I have macOS 10.13
bazel version 0.15.2-homebrew

I am trying to install bazel 0.4.5 to be able to finish my tensorflow GPU support installation. there is a problem where I have to have bazel 0.4.5 instead 0.15.2 (what a pain)

I have downloaded the binary file bazel-0.4.5-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
I ran chmod +x bazel-0.4.5-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
then ./bazel-0.4.5-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user

when running the installation i get following error

```
Uncompressing......
/Users/jvivas/.bazelrc already exists, moving it to /Users/jvivas/.bazelrc.bak.
Problem with java installation: couldn't find/access rt.jar in 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

looks like I can not run bazel 0.4.5 with JDK 10..here is where I dont know what do...may be I have to downgrade the JDK to 8 or 9, which it seems there was another problem with it.

Have anyone ran into this issue before?

Thanks